# Include .Rtex as a chapter in latex

Tags: input, r

I have an Rtex that contains:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{./Introduction/Introduction}

\chapter{Thesis Outline}
\input{./Outline/Outline_Chapter}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{./References/Upgrade}

\end{document}
```

I was to include some R code into the file "./Outline/Outline_Chapter". Is there any way to have that as Outline_Chapter.Rtex and still be input/included to the overall document?

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 1):

The following works in Overleaf (naming main file *.Rtex).

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{filecontents*}{tmp999.Rtex}
<<>>=
rnorm(3)
@
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\input{tmp999}
\end{document}
```

[image: Overleaf output]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `\input` or `\include`, you have to use [knitr's knit_child function](https://yihui.org/knitr/demo/child/). For this to work, the main file and your outine chapter file must have the .Rtex file extension. As long as you do not run R code in Introduction.tex, you can keep this file as it is. For your example, this would look like:

**main.Rtex**

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\chapter{Introduction}
\input{./Introduction/Introduction}

\chapter{Thesis Outline}
\Sexpr{knit_child('Outline/Outline_Chapter.Rtex')}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{./References/Upgrade}

\end{document}
```

**Outline/Outline_Chapter.Rtex**

```
This is your Thesis Outline.

<<testplot, out.width='2in'>>=
boxplot(1:10)
@
```